# Unable to read data from Redux store in the React app

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my React code where using the useSelector, I'm trying to read a property called currentUser from the store but it not working :-

```
  import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
  const currentUsr = useSelector(state => {
    console.log('state:', state);
    //state.get('currentUser');
    state.currentUser;
  });
  console.log('currentUsr', currentUsr);
```

If I console print only the state then it is coming like this :-

```
Map {size: 7, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
size: 7
__altered: false
__hash: undefined
__ownerID: undefined
_root: ArrayMapNode {ownerID: OwnerID, entries: Array(7)}
__proto__: KeyedCollection
```

I can see the data in the Redux store using the Redux dev tools plugin (refer screenshot):-
[image]

It is always coming as undefined.

This is my user info reducer :-

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import * as actions from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = Immutable.Map({});

export const setUserInfo = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.ADD_USER:
      return state.merge({
        uid: action.uid,
        permissions: action.permissions,
        locale: action.locale,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I tried to debug it a lot but still unable to read the currentUser from the Redux store. I would really appreciate your help on this as I'm completely blocked with it. Thank you

Comment: You're not returning `state.currentUser`. Did you try `return state.currentUser;`?

Comment: sorry, it is not working. I have worked with Redux in the past but never got blocked like this.. If you see the screenshot of redux dev tools then it is pretty easy to get data from it using state.currentUser. Not sure where to check. Just FYI, import { setUserInfo as currentUser } from './userInfoReducer'; const appReducer = combineReducers({ authReducer, currentUser })

Answer (score 0):

When you use useSelector() or useDispatch(), it should return state and dispatch action respectively. In above code return statement is missing in useSelector().

You can write in either way:

```
const currentUsr = useSelector(state => {
    console.log('state:', state);
    //state.get('currentUser');
    return state.currentUser;
  });
```

or

```
const currentUsr = useSelector(state => state.currentUser);
```

Update:
Try mutating your state like this:

```
 case actions.ADD_USER: {
    let newState = {...state, {
        uid: action.uid,
        permissions: action.permissions,
        locale: action.locale,
      }
  }

  return state.merge(newState);
}
```

Comment: sorry, it is not working. I tried both options but not working. I have worked with Redux in the past but never got blocked like this.. If you see the screenshot of redux dev tools then it is pretty easy to get data from it using state.currentUser. Not sure where to check. Just FYI, import { setUserInfo as currentUser } from './userInfoReducer';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  authReducer,
  currentUser
});

Comment: Finally, I found the solution...Problem was I was not reading from the redux correctly using the Immutable JS Map. As Immutable JS stores the redux data in the form of map so I was supposed to send the key in it. This code worked for me  :- const currentUsr = useSelector(state => state.get('currentUser'));
  console.log('currentUsr uid', currentUsr.get('uid'));

Answer (score 0):

I was not reading the data from Redux using the Immutable JS properyly. In Immutable, data gets stored in the form of Map so I was supposed to send the key as 'uid' in its get().

This code worked for me :-

```
const currentUsr = useSelector(state => state.get('currentUser'));
console.log('currentUsr uid', currentUsr.get('uid'));
```